# Consul server joining wrong cluster

Tags: consul

I'm having some issues trying to create a cluster of consul servers when there is a previous cluster on the same network.

All these new servers use the same configuration except the bind property, retry-join and datacenter. Certificates, certificates keys and encryption passes are all the same. I've assumed there should be no issue since the hostnames are similar enough to use the same certificates.

Yet, those new servers join the previous cluster instead of just creating their own. Which is not what is desired at all.

I'm starting to think that the certificates might have something to do with those servers joining a cluster instead of creating a new one, but might need confirmation. Help?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was stopping and removing everything and did everything from the scratch...

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with the encryption keys. In your case you intend to have separate clusters in one network, but you use the same encryption key. Try to use unique encryption key, one for each cluster. Here is similar discussion: [link](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/4074)